# Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined error but only in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, knockout.js, cross-browser

I'm using knockout.js to create a drag/drop diary for a customer, and I've just switched to testing in chrome where I get this mysterious error `"Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined"` in the `parseBindingString` function of knockout however this template is tested and working in FireFox/IFE10.

the error is thrown on the `css: { blackout: workingHours($parent.DaysArray(0), $parents[1].ViewDate()).startTime.getTime() == workingHours($parent.DaysArray(0), $parents[1].ViewDate()).finishTime.getTime() }` binding, however in the debugger context the `node` local variable has 4 registered child nodes as expected so knockout must be trying to do some serious tree navigation here, which simply isn't necessary for my `workingHours()` function or to add the `blackout` class to the current node.

I presume this has only arisen in chrome due to minor differences in the way the DOM is constructed between browsers, but could anyone offer some advice on how I can resolve this kind of issue? or things to check?

```
<td data-bind="
    css: { 
        blackout: workingHours($parent.DaysArray(0), $parents[1].ViewDate()).startTime.getTime() == workingHours($parent.DaysArray(0), $parents[1].ViewDate()).finishTime.getTime() }">
    <div class="unallocated-booking">
        <div class="status-bar-holder mini-status-bar-holder" data-bind="
            template: { 
                name: 'unallocated-booking-template', 
                foreach: todaysBookings($parent.DaysArray(0), bookings, $parents[1].ViewDate()) }"/>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="
        attr: { 
            'data-init-droppable': false }, 
        class: { 
            droppable: isWorkDay( $parent.DaysArray(0), $parents[1].ViewDate() ) }, 
        template: { 
            name: 'week-cell-template', 
            foreach: todaysBookings($parent.DaysArray(0), bookings, $parents[1].ViewDate()) }"/>
</td>
```

Minor aside (probably needing a separate question) but ironically I only tried loading in chrome because the `attr`/`class`/`template` binding on the last element seems to be ignoring the `class` & `attr` bindings since I added the `template` binding and I wanted to debug in chrome. But since I've got the attention of all you knockout.js aficionado's already I thought I'd plug that in here :p. Might even be relevant though I can't see an issue with my syntax.

Comment: If possible it would help to extend the code a bit into a repro, possibly even add a jsfiddle. This would make it much easier to help.

Comment: hmm, this template is the lynch pin between about 5 levels of templating, won't be too easy to make short of listing all my code but I'll see what I can do!

Comment: sadly haven't got it working in time and moving onto something else now.. a repro will have to wait :S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout.js wasn't the cause of this issue

turned out to be a difference in the way the `getElementsByTagName()` works in Chrome as it doesn't require (or work when) the namespace of the searched element to be specified.